# jQuery: fade in 1 element on hover while fading out many others in a smooth fashion

Tags: jquery

In my page I have severals divs. When the user hovers over 1 div I want to fade out all other elements except the one the user is hovering over.
This works with the code below, however:
When the user moves fast with his mouse over all items, it appears as if the fading proces for each item is queued and even though the user is no longer moving his mouse, the fading out continues until the queue is empty.
To test, check my code below and move your mouse for example from the left to the right and notice the effect.

What I want to achieve is that the current item on which the user hovers has opacity of 1 while the others are then given 0.7.
How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{background-color:Red;}

.elementhighlight
{
    font-weight:bold !important;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

.elementhovered{background-color:#AE2460 !important;}

.element 
{
width:140px;
height:130px;
padding-left:4px;
padding-right:4px;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
}


.element0{background-color:#FFF;}
.element1{background-color:#E6E4E0;}

.element .title,.element1 .title{
font: 12px Helvetica, verdana !important;    
text-align:center;
padding-top:4px;
padding-bottom:4px;
color:#666666;
}



</style>

</head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('.element').hover(function () {
        var curelement = $(this);            
        curelement.fadeTo(500, 1.0);
        curelement.addClass('elementhovered');

        curelement.stop().fadeTo(500, 1.0);
        $('.element').not('.elementhovered').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.7); 
        curelement.find('.title').addClass('elementhighlight');
    },
    function () {
        $('.element').fadeTo(300, 1.0);
        var curelement = $(this);
        curelement.removeClass('elementhovered');
        curelement.find('.title').removeClass('elementhighlight');
    });
});
</script>


<body>


<div class="element element0">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="element element1">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="element element0">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="element element1">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="element element0">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>
<div class="element element1">
    <div class="title">Item</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.stop()` prevent the queue from building:

```
curelement.stop().fadeTo(500, 1.0);

$('.element').not('.elementhovered').stop()fadeTo(500, 0.7);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use .stop(false, true) depending on the effect you are after. Or, if you want to "prevent the accidental firing of animations", you can use the hoverIntent plugin, http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: I updated my code but no go. I'm not sure how to use stop() method. The effect I'm after is this:
user hovers over item 1, all other items fade out, except item 1.
user moves mouse to item 2, all other items fade out, except item 2.
etc.
Now when the user moves fast over various items, an effect is started. However, I only want to have the effect relevant for the element the user is CURRENTLY hovering.Meaning when user moves from item 1 to item 10 starting at 1, the effect on item 1 is triggered and all other items are dimmed. But this proces should be stopped when user moves to the next item.

Comment: See here something what I'd like to achieve: http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/gb/en/the-virgin-experience.html

Comment: Added `.stop()` to all your `fadeTo()` elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/NbDdU/ If you want them to all be not faded-out for a fraction of a second when the user moves their mouse, like on the link you provided, replace the four instances of `.stop()` with `.stop(false, true)`, as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NbDdU/1/